# GPIO pins with pijuice hat

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-4, electronics, robotics

I am currently building a website controlled bb8 based on a raspberry pi 4b, and 2 12v motors controlled by a wma4000 relays module(4 relays, 2 for each motor are used to move forward and backwards). i have a script and index running and working with the gpio pins 17,22,23,27 sending voltage to the relays and moving the motors. my issue at hand how to run the raspberry pi by battery. i was given a pijuice hat zero even tho its not for the 4b i made a bold assumption and made it work with a ribbon cable extension i had lying around, the 5v pins work as intended but now with the pijuice hat the gpio pins aren’t working. i tried installing wiringpi with no avail. how would i go about controlling the gpio pins a pijuice hat on. i can provide images and code if needed.
[bb8](https://imgur.com/a/48mc1tg)
Thanks everyone

Comment: Try writing in English. Use paragraphs. You have provided absolutely no technical details of what you have done.